# Should we allow special characters or numbers in name field?

Tags: forms, validation

I need a generic validation for first and last name field that will be used everywhere.
Currently I'm using:

/^[A-Za-z]?[A-Za-z ]*$/

Comment: Why are you validating peoples names? A name isn't like a credit card number which can fail. A name is a name.

Comment: I point you to a popular old article - [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Answer (score 23):

**Yes** you should!

Your suggestion about having a validation rule would be a very bad idea. Did you know, the world's most common last name is 王?

Here is a classic article that you need to read: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

> All of these assumptions are **wrong**:
>
> - (...)
> - People’s names are written in ASCII.
> - (...)
> - People’s names do not contain numbers.
> - (...)

Comment: Nowadays, instead of referring to the original article, I tend to link to [Falsehoods Programmers Believe Aboudt Names - With Examples](https://shinesolutions.com/2018/01/08/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names-with-examples/).

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure regarding the code your using but I think if you'll have a small guidelines tooltip that will state that says not to use special characters in the first and last name that will be a nice UX , though i dont know what the application your using .. and not sure how you will apply it there ..(this forum has a tooltip like that for the password type here I found that very usfull)

Comment: People's names ***do*** contain special characters.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think I would find it a Good User Experience to be told I couldn't use characters that are in my name when inputting my name.

Comment: @JonW correct. Same with length restrictions, I've seen a screenshot of poor Mr. "Li" that couldn't get past the "minimum 3 characters" barrier

Comment: @jonW true, you're right I thought you might be referring to sign like that .. @%^ in a user name .. so you are right!

Comment: Unless you are attempting to enforce legal requirements on names in a particular jurisdiction, what purpose could you have in restricting what people are allowed to call themselves?