# What should be allowed in full name in a sign up form?

Tags: user-expectation, profile

Building an international web app like Quora or twitter to serve many countries.
What should be allowed for person's name in profile.

- Only one full name field or first name and last name
- How many minimum/maximum characters
- Only English (A-Z,a-z,spaces) or more characters (dot, etc. or more languages, unicode, utf-8, utf-16, what?)

What rules are being used by zomato, twitter, quora?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Merging firstname/last name into one field](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/15770/merging-firstname-last-name-into-one-field)

Comment: Please show what research you have done to try to answer your question. As it stands there is no actual indication that you've made any effort here.

Comment: International websites need full character support ,additionally first and last name doesnt exist in all cultures and names can get very long. 40 characters seems reasonable to me.

Comment: You may want to have a read here: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/61908/should-we-allow-special-characters-or-numbers-in-name-field/61910#61910

Answer (score 2):

You could just offer a single Box *Username* where the user can decide weather to use first-/lastname-system or something else

Answer (score -2):

Normally a persons name should be the second name. When we create the form we will say to the user first name or sure name and second name.

Name suggests 35 characters but put as: 70 characters maximum, first name length was 46, and email 255 characters.

It applies to all languages

Comment: There are people whose names don't fit in the parameters you gave (I went to university with one) - names get longer than you think.